# Issue with referer header on php script for detecting domain name

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I make script that detect whitelisted domain name when send request to .php file on my server. And when detect that specific whitelisted domain in script show json data.

Pls check my code:

```
<?php

$allowedDomains = array('www.example1.com', 'www.example2.com', 'example3.com');
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$domain = parse_url($referer);
if(in_array( $domain['host'], $allowedDomains)) {

$inputArray =  array (
                'name' => 'TEST',
                'version' => '1.0.0',
                'download_url' => 'http://example.com',
                'sections' => 
                array (
                  'description' => '',
    ),
);

$encodedJSON = json_encode($inputArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
print($encodedJSON);

} else {
    echo "you are not allowed to post at this page";
    exit();
}

?>
```

Issue is that "referer" header cant process Wordpress, I am not sure what other I can change?

I am using a script from this GitHub https://github.com/YahnisElsts/plugin-update-checker#self-hosted-plugins-and-themes check the issue that every time returns the message "you are not allowed to post at this page" because of "referer" header cant process WordPress request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue with php script for detecting domain name, wp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66936932/issue-with-php-script-for-detecting-domain-name-wp)

Comment: I am not sure that will work on wp request ?

Comment: Please don't just repost a question because it was closed. Go black to the original question and improve it. You need to explain your problem better. See [ask]

Comment: But they will not remove closed tag if I improve that question?

Comment: They should in theory, people can vote to re-open. That's how it's supposed to work.

Comment: I test code for one member that sends but I see the same issue, What can I do to fix? Can anyone try to fix this in this thread? For now I know Issue is that "referer" header cant process Wordpress

Comment: Your need to provide more details. For example, what the actual problem is: Does your choice return JSON although you don't want it to? Or does it not return JSON although you expect it to? For example, have you debugged the code and can show what the referer looks like? If it maybe empty? For example, what is the site that is referring to your site?

Comment: I am using a script from this GitHub https://github.com/YahnisElsts/plugin-update-check the issue that every time returns the message "you are not allowed to post at this page" because of "referer" header cant process Wordpress.

Comment: I am doing this section: https://github.com/YahnisElsts/plugin-update-checker#self-hosted-plugins-and-themes I want to successfully detect domain name and display json data.